# How do I get rid of the subscript indices error in my code?

Tags: matlab

```
length = 31 ;
while length < 0 
    length = input('enter a value greater than 0:')
end

pounds = 26905;

elasticity = 45941267 ;

width = 4.3  
while width < 0 
    width = input('enter a value greater than 0:')
end
height = 1.2 
while height < 0 
    height = input('enter a value greater than 0:');
end

I = (width*height^3)/12;
a = linspace(1,200)';
b = length - a ;


if a >= 0

maximum = (-pounds*b(length.^2-(b.^2))^(3/2))/(9*sqrt(3)*elasticity*I*length)'



elseif b >= 0

  maximum = (-pounds*a(length.^2-(a.^2))^(3/2))/(9*sqrt(3)*elasticity*I*length)'  

end
```

It happens at this line:

```
maximum = (-pounds*b(length.^2-(b.^2))^(3/2))/(9*sqrt(3)*elasticity*I*length)'
```

I need my code to come out with these numbers so i can print them in a table and be done with my code.

Comment: One evident error (maybe) is `if  a>=0`  and `elseif ...`. The first condition is always true because a = 1:200. So, the second part is never evaluated.

Comment: The error is most surely happening at this part of the line: `...b(length.^2-(b.^2))...`.  In your code, `b` is actually a vector, and since you're indexing into `b`, you must ensure that the indices are positive and integer values.  However, it seems that you're assuming that `b` is a function of some sorts.  The same can be said about your other part of the `if` statement where it's `...a(length.^2-(b.^2))...`.  I have no idea what your code is supposed to do, so please edit your post to describe what the desired behaviour is.

Comment: Just a comment, try to avoid use of words that are built in Matlab functions.  For example `length` is a function that will give you the maximum of the dimensions of an array.  Overwriting it can potentially cause problems.  For example `lenVar = length(myVar);` may not produce what someone expects.

Answer (score 0):

As @rayryeng stated, the problem you hay is that you are indexing into b.
If you examine `length^2 - (b.^2)` you get:

```
61    120    177    232    285    336    385    432    477    520
561    600    637    672    705    736    765    792    817    840
861    880    897    912    925    936    945    952    957    960
961    960    957    952    945    936    925    912    897    880
861    840    817    792    765    736    705    672    637    600
561    520    477    432    385    336    285    232    177    120
61      0    -63   -128   -195   -264   -335   -408   -483   -560
... snipped
```

The fourth value is: `232` which is greater than b's length (200 in this case). That triggers the first error, but even if you were able to continue you'll eventually get to negative values (for an index! Another error there)